# Eclipse locking up when saving some files on network drive

Tags: eclipse, coldfusion

I am having an issue with saving certain files on a mapped network drive in Eclipse. Most of the files on the drive save just fine. However when I save certain files eclipse will lock up and has to be force closed. I have compared the files that save and the files that do not. There is no difference in the file privileges. The only thing I am noticing is the files that stall tend to be larger files. A 19KB will save just fine but larger files like a 493KB seem to cause the issue. Anyone else experience this issue? I am writing Coldfusion files, using eclipse 4.4.1, windows 7 with mapped network shares. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I experience similar issues with dreamweaver and a network drive, but I'm convinced that it's unrelated to ColdFusion or Dreamweaver.  If you are on Windows, try some things on Windows Explorer and see it they are slow.  Also, open the files with a text editor, add or remove some white space, and save the changes.  See if it's still slow.

Comment: This is common problem and why we usually suggest local storage for development. Sorry I don't have a better anwser. The underlying Java for working with mapped drives is simply balky on a windows machine. it's a tad better on Linux (though frankly not much!).

Comment: Saving the files works flawlessly in Notepad++. I never have any issues with the files through Windows Explorer. Unfortunately the environment I am working in is requiring me to work from the mapped drive. Local would be best for sure but at the moment it's unfortunately not an option.

Comment: Maybe the computer gods are dropping you a hint about encapsulation.  I took a quick boo at our systems and the only files bigger than 100 KB that I found were complete function libraries downloaded from cflib.org.

Comment: Very true. We have done some refactoring of other components. The large files I have noted are cfc's that have been built over the years by many hands. They could definitely use some overhaul but getting the powers that be to understand that is another story all together. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After multiple attempts to resolve the issue (over days) I have come across a strange solution. I saved a slightly larger file (168KB) and Eclipse acted like it was locking up again. Window title indicated "Not Responding" eclipse washed out with a transparent overlay etc. I switched over to my email, came back and it was fine. I made a change to the file and it saved right away. No issues. So I opened up a larger file (493KB) made a small edit, saved and let it act like it was locking up. Continued to work in another program came back a few minutes later and all was well. Made another quick change to the file, saved and what do you know its saving right away. Pretty strange behavior. So basically once the file saves once from then on out it saves quickly.

Comment: yes that's typical, but not acceptable - particulary for SVN commits and updates which can run painfully slow to a network drive involving dozens if not hundreds of files.